# How this integral is derived? : Vasicek Bond Price

Tags: integration

This problem comes from deriving Vasicek Bond Price formula.

The equation is like below (α is constant)

$∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt + ∫^T_0∫^s_0σ^2e^{-(s+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}duds$

= $2∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt$

I think this is the reason that two part is same, so it just multiplied by 2. However,

- $2∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt$ = $\frac{σ^2}{α^2}∫^T_0(1 +e^{-2αt}-2e^{-αt})dt$

I don't understand above this.

I tried to like this but it gets no such things.

-My trial

- $2∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt$ = $\frac{σ^2}{α}∫^T_0(∫^t_0e^{-(t+u)}(e^{2αu}-1)du)dt$
  = $\frac{σ^2}{α}∫^T_0(∫^t_0e^{(-t+(2α-1)u)}-e^{-(t+u)}du)dt$ = $\frac{σ^2}{α}∫^T_0(e^{-t}∫^t_0e^{(2α-1)u}-e^{-u}du)dt$ = $\frac{σ^2}{α}∫^T_0(e^{-t}(∫^t_0e^{(2α-1)u}du-∫^t_0e^{-u}du))dt$

How can I do this?
Please give me a help.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_0^T f(t)\,dt = \int_0^T f(s)\,ds$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes so $∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt + ∫^T_0∫^s_0σ^2e^{-(s+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}duds$

= $2∫^T_0∫^t_0σ^2e^{-(t+u)}\frac{e^{2αu}-1}{2α}dudt$ this can be possible